# Plot regression line in each subplot of facetgrid

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

```
def global_regression(x, y, **kwargs):
    # Plot
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ax = plt.scatter(x.values, y.values)

    # Draw 'red' regression line
    x_plot = np.linspace(ax.get_xlim()[0], ax.get_xlim()[1], 100)
    m, b = np.polyfit(x.values, y.values, 1)
    plt.plot(x_plot, m * x_plot + b, color='red', alpha=0.5)

   # Draw diagonal 1:1 line
   ax.plot(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(), ls='--', c='.3', alpha=0.5)

   # Create nice-looking grid for ease of visualization
   ax.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
   ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.15)

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='val')
g.map(global_regression, 'actual', 'predicted')
g.add_legend()
g.set(alpha=0.25)
```

In the code above, I want to create a facetgris and use the `global_regression` function to draw a regression line. However, I get this error:
`*** AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'get_xlim'` for `ax.get_alim()[0]`. How to fix this? I do not want to use `regplot`

Comment: [mcve] of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.scatter` returns a `PathCollection`. Despite you calling it `ax` this is not an axes and hence cannot be treated as such, i.e. it does not have a `get_xlim` attribute. Hence the error.

Instead call the scatter whatever you like and get the axes via `plt.gca()`.

```
foo = plt.scatter(x.values, y.values)
ax = plt.gca()
```

Note that you might run into new errors with the code from above, but one would need to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that.